# How to stop explorer Json downloading strange bahaviour?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i can not bind Json data to table. Also internet explorer wants to download Json data. How to stop explorer download request and fill table. i have been reading more stackoverflow questions and googling articles. i can not understand why knockout.js cannot bind data. i have been learned binding arhitecture in knockout and json binding.

like That:

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/3rRUQ/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5EWDG/

i would like to use binding theese methods. but i can not stopping iexplorer downloading behavior.

```
  var result = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Contact/GetEmployees/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Employees);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
};

ko.utils.arrayMap(result, function (i) { Directory.list.push(new Employee(i.EmployeeCode, i.EmployeeName)); });
```

#### also :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetPerson";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>GetPerson</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Person(FirstName, LastName, Friends) {
        var self = this;
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(FirstName);
        self.LastName = ko.observable(LastName);
        self.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.FirstName() + ' ' + self.LastName();
        })
        self.Friends = ko.observableArray(Friends);
        self.AddFriend = function () {
            self.Friends.push(new Person('new', 'friend'));
        };
        self.DeleteFriend = function (friend) {
            self.Friends.remove(friend);
        };
    }

    var viewModel = new Person();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Person/GetPerson',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (jsonResult) {
                viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonResult, mapping);
                console.log(viewModel);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            }
        });
    });


    var mapping = {
        create: function (options) {
            var person = options.data,
            friends = ko.utils.arrayMap(person.Friends, function (friend) {
                return new Person(friend.FirstName, friend.LastName);
            });

            return new Person(person.FirstName, person.LastName, friends);
        }
    };

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: FirstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: LastName" /></p>
<p>Full name: <span data-bind="text: FullName" /></p>
<p>#Friends: <span data-bind="text: Friends().length" /></p>
@*Allow maximum of 5 friends*@
<p><button data-bind="click: AddFriend, text:'add new friend', enable:Friends().length < 5" /></p>

@*define how friends should be rendered*@
<table data-bind="foreach: Friends">
    <tr>
        <td>First name: <input data-bind="value: FirstName" /></td>
        <td>Last name: <input data-bind="value: LastName" /></td>
        <td>Full name: <span data-bind="text: FullName" /></td> 
        <td><button data-bind="click: function(){ $parent.DeleteFriend($data) }, text:'delete'"/></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Controller Method:

```
  public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Person/

        public ActionResult GetPerson()
        {
            Person person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "My",
                LastName = "Name",
                Friends = new List<Person>
                        {
                             new Person{FirstName = "Friend", LastName="Number1"},
                             new Person{FirstName = "Friend", LastName="Number2"}
                        }
            };
            return Json(person, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 //return Json(person,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  Not working
        }
    }
```

How to solve binding and downloading problem?

Comment: Can you post your `ContactController.GetEmployees` method?

Comment: Propably your server is serving the json with the wrong content type (should be "application/json").

Comment: GetEmployees: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682088/how-to-fill-a-html-table-with-json-data-by-using-knockout-js-and-jquery

Comment: @newesv i added. But return Json(person,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  also not working.